# How can I use the Verifone Printer 900 on Windows?

Tags: windows, printing, serial-port

Does anyone know how the Verifone Printer 900 works? I'm unable to print from Windows, can't find anything like a driver.

I'm already using a serial to USB adapter. I'm using COM3.

Comment: I'm sure someone knows how it works, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a specialised receipt-printer for a point-of-sale (POS) system, not a general purpose printer for other Windows applications.

You could try treating it as a dumb text printer (though no doubt it is capable of more). In XP for example you can use Start, Printers; Add a Printer, ... select Manufacturer "Generic", Model "Generic / Text Only".

If that works, you can move on to see if it is compatible with ancient dot-matrix devices like the Epson MX-80 or the IBM Proprinter.